# vtkImageActor Opacity with vtkVolume

Tags: c++, vtk

Is not vtkImageActor transparent when I have a vtkVolume in renderer? 
If I change vtkImageActor-> opacity (0.5) I have the image in the input 
scured, plus the 3D does not show on the other side.

Opacity in 100%

[image]

Opacity in 50%

[image]

code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkBMPReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkBMPReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(local.c_str());
reader->Update();

ImageActor->GetMapper()->SetInputData(reader->GetOutput());
ImageActor->Update();

ImageActor->SetOpacity(opacity);

Renderer->AddActor(ImageActor);

Renderer->Render();
RenderWindow->Render();
```

my vtkVolume uses the vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.
The settings look very similar to the example https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/VolumeRendering/Cxx/GPURenderDemo.cxx [ using CompositeRamp ]

I use version 8.0.1 of vtk on windows 10 x64.

I tried using vtkLookupTable and vtkImageMapToColors, but I had the same result.
Is this normal in vtk?

Comment: What version of VTK are you using? And what platform are you running it on? What volume mapper type are you using exactly?

Comment: Have you seen this example? 
https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/VolumeRendering/HAVSVolumeMapper/

Comment: my mapper is vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper . I use vtk 8.0.1 in Windows 10 64x

Comment: If I use vtkActor with vtkDataSetMapper for mapped my image everything works fine. The opacity has effect. But, i need to use vtkImageactor.